# git svn ambiguous argument 'HEAD'

Tags: git, svn

```
   $ git svn clone -s http://a_repo local_dir ( by default this brings me r1 ) to hdd
    Initialized empty Git repository in d:/Temp/local_dir/.git/
    r1 = some_SHA (refs/remotes/trunk)

   $ cd local_dir
   $ git svn rebase
   fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
   Use '--' to separate paths from revisions
   log --no-color --no-decorate --first-parent --pretty=medium HEAD: command returned error: 128
```

How can I actually checkout the repo?

I also tried without rebasing, to use `fetch`, but it only brings one revision at a time. We have several thousand commits, at this rate, it will take days to copy the repository.

Comment: you mean `git svn clone` brings only ONE revision? You are using `-s`, is your SVN repo really in standard layout? Normally, `git svn clone` shoud also create a working copy.

Answer (score 9):

If you get only one commit out of your SVN repo, I assume that the SVN repo is not in standard layout but you tell `git svn` that it is.

```
git svn clone http://a_repo local_dir
```

(i.e. without the `-s` flag) should be able to clone the SVN repo. If this works, retry the clone and specify your trunk, tags and branches directories as described in the [docs of git-svn](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn).

Comment: My repository is in standard layout. I also tried via -T, specifying trunk as parameter, same thing. I remember reading somewhere that if you start an svn clone via `fetch`, you can only continue via `fetch`. Maybe it's the reason why fetch "works" ( getting only one revision for each call )? Because a git clone is an init followed by a fetch?

Comment: @Senthess: Does a simple `git svn clone http://a_repo local_dir` (i.e. without any repo-layout-info-params) work or not? Also, `git svn fetch` sould bring up all revisions, not only one. You do a `git svn clone` into a fresh directory without repo, right?

Comment: I'm no longer at work, and unfortunately I cannot test this. I will write the result in the morning. I am cloning into a fresh directory ( no files exist prior to clone ).

Comment: clone brings me the first 15 revisions and stops. I started a fetch afterwards, but it still brings me one revision at a time.

Comment: In that case, I assume that your SVN repo is somehow broken. Are you able to browse the first revisions of your SVN repo?

Comment: Yes. The SVN client works perfectly. I am thinking of something else ... what if the connection gets dropped? Couldn't this be a reason?

Comment: @Senthess: Then you should get a message that the connection was dropped. Cannot help you in that case...

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't get such a message. It just stops.

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution to this? I'm experiencing the same problem

Answer (score 2):

```
git svn clone [your-repo-url] -s
# OR 
git svn clone [your-repo-url] -T [your-trunk-dir] -t [your-tags-dir] -b [your-branches-dir]
```

If you don't specify -r flag (as above), then you need to

```
git svn fetch
```

Answer (score 2):

This error occurs when you clone a **branch** instead of the whole SVN repository.

If your repo URL looks like `https://svnserver/project/repo/trunk` or `https://svnserver/project/branches/pre-something`, change the clone command to:

```
git svn clone https://svnserver/project/repo --stdlayout
```